# Create alerts in enterprise application in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-alerts

Is there any way to monitor any changes to the owners list on the enterprise application. To setup alerts on the changes to the users.

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up an alert that triggers when there are changes to application ownership based on the [activity filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/security-operations-applications#application-configuration-changes) in the Azure AD Logs, **Activity: Add owner to application**. There is a [Microsoft Sentinel template for capturing this here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/blob/master/Detections/AuditLogs/ChangestoApplicationOwnership.yaml). You can integrate these logs with Microsoft Sentinel, Azure Monitor, Microsoft Defender, and other tools to capture and alert based on these activities.

[image]

Azure Monitor also allows you to create an Activity Log alert rule to fire based on particular activity such as "Add owner to application." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-new-alert-rule?tabs=metric